# Makefile: run the same command with different arguments on different targets

Tags: makefile

## Code

Consider the following makefile snippet:

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

build:
    docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=false -t $(COMMIT) .
rebuild:
    docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=true  -t $(COMMIT) .
```

## The problem

The only difference between `build` and `rebuild` is the value of the `--no-cache` parameter. Obviously, rewriting the same command with a slight change is a bad practice; it breaks the DRY principle, and if I ever need to change something else in the command - for example, the value of `-t` - I would have to change it across all relevant targets.

I had something like this in mind:

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
NO_CACHE := false

build:
    docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=$(NO_CACHE) -t $(COMMIT) .
rebuild:
    NO-CACHE = true
    make build
```

I tried playing with the variables, with no luck.

## My question

What would be an elegant way to write the `docker build` command once, and have each target alter its parameter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [constructed variable names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/):

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

build_NOCACHE   = false
rebuild_NOCACHE = true

build rebuild:
        docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=$($@_NOCACHE) -t $(COMMIT) .
```

Or you can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

build:   NOCACHE = false
rebuild: NOCACHE = true

build rebuild:
        docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=$(NOCACHE) -t $(COMMIT) .
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Clear and and to the point. However, Seems that I have a deeper question - would you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488942/makefile-propagating-variables-to-dependent-targets please?

Comment: Target-specific variables are _inherited_ by prerequisites (see the manual).  The original idea was just what you had in mind: for example you set some debug flags on a `debug` target then create `debug: all` and if you run `make debug` the debug flags are inherited by all prerequisites down the build chain.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the call function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function)

Positional arguments are specified from 1 to n and used in the command definition as `$(1)`, `$(2)`, `$(n)`.

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

DOCKER_BUILD_CMD = docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache=$(1) -t $(COMMIT) .

build:
    $(call DOCKER_BUILD_CMD, false)

rebuild:
    $(call DOCKER_BUILD_CMD, true)
```

Comment: It would work, but I think that using target specific variables is more readable and elegant.