# Makefile: Propagating variables to dependent targets

Tags: makefile

This is a continuation of [Makefile: run the same command with different arguments on different targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488712/makefile-run-the-same-command-with-different-arguments-on-different-targets/44488843#44488843).

## Code

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

images := base web proxy lb users api

$(images): base
    @echo "Building $@"
    docker build -f Dockerfile.$@ --no-cache=true -t $@:$(COMMIT) . 

build: $(images)
rebuild: $(images) # I want this to run with --no-cache=true
```

Essentially, `build` calls all `image` targets (`base` being the first one), and runs `docker build` with `--no-cache=true` for each one.

## The problem

I would like to have a `rebuild` target which runs all `image` targets with `--no-cache=false` rather than `--no-cache=true`, without duplicating the code. I guess that the right way is to set a variable in `rebuild` and `build` whose scope would cover dependent targets like any of the `images`.

## My question

How do I define a variable in a target whose scope covers all dependent targets?

Comment: See [my answer to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488712/makefile-run-the-same-command-with-different-arguments-on-different-targets/44488843#44488843) and get rid of target-specific variables altogether.

Comment: No, target-specific variables will do this automatically, as Artur's answer shows.  IMO, they're much better than using `call`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite similar, like in mentioned question:

```
images := base web proxy lb users api

$(images):
    @echo $@ docker --no-cache=$(NO_CACHE)

build: NO_CACHE=true
rebuild: NO_CACHE=false

rebuild build: $(images)
```

You may want to set a default value for `NO_CACHE` in case you would like to call `make base` for example.

Comment: Perfect, that's a very elegant solution. Did not know that target-specific variables propagate nicely to dependent tasks. Thanks!